# Multiple triggers on the same firestore collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is it allowed to have multiple onWrite triggers on the same firestore collection?
I already have one onWrite event in my cloud functions:

```
exports.modifyUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
...
}
```

Is it ok to have another one? I know I could combine it in the same trigger but my application is in production already and I really don't want to break anything by messing up the existing database trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is totally acceptable to have multiple triggers on the same collection. They'll fire independently of each other, and run on different containers.

Note that you'll pay extra for having them isolated, as running them separate doubles the number of invocations, and probably reduces your options for running code in parallel (which would reduce the the CPU and GB seconds).

Comment: The functions running on different containers, does that imply that my new function 'should' not break the existing one?

Comment: Correct. Each container runs no more than one function at a time.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen can you elaborate on "reduces your options for running code in parallel"?  

We're looking to have many GCP functions triggered on the same collection and same event "onCreate", currently 5 but potentially more. 

We want be sure that these functions will not compete for the same CPU, time or anything that causes other unexpected behavior when scaling.